# Change slave ID address

Tags: python, modbus

I'm trying to change the slave ID address. I'm using GECON TCP-508N Super Smart S8-3CN controller and by default the ID address is 1 which in the following code is `unit=1`. I'm reading the coils but I don't seem to find how to change the slave's ID address. Here's my code in Python:

```py
import pymodbus
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient


client = ModbusClient(
    method="rtu", port="COM5", timeout=1,
    stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity="N", baudrate=9600)

def main():
    global client

    connection = client.connect()
    if connection:
        print("Connected")
    else:
        print("No connection")

    response = client.read_coils(address=1, count=8, unit=1)
    print(response.bits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: So you want to change the address from the default, which is 1, to a custom value, which is also 1?

Comment: *"the ID address [...] which in the following code is `unit=1`"* – are you sure it is not `address=1`?

Comment: Perhaps it is not possible to change the slave address via the serial connection. It may be that the address can only be changed through a configuration tool, see this (?) [manual](http://bends.se/bendcms/files/hardware/GECON_TCP-508N_io_module/TCP_user_manual.pdf).